# My For loop is incorrectly timed, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I am having trouble with my For loop, as it is not correctly timed for some reason. I am having it click my 'alien' every 5 seconds (which you will see in the code), and it's supposed to increase every time you buy a worker. So if you have 2 workers, it's 2 aliens per 5 seconds, 3 aliens is 3 per 5 seconds and so on. However, when I have 2 or more workers it acts like I want to click the alien twice for every worker.

What I want:
1 worker = automatically clicked once per 5 seconds //
2 workers = automatically clicked twice per 5 seconds
etc.

What it INCORRECTLY does:
1 worker works how I want //
2 workers = automatically clicked twice per 5 seconds, each click is worth 2
etc.

Here is the variable that runs the for loop:

```
var workerCheck = setInterval(function(){
        var workers = parseInt($("#Workers").text());
            if( workers > 0 ){
                for(var i = 0; i < workers; i++){
                $("#Alien").click();       
                }
            }
    },5000);
```

Here is the pastebin link to my entire code: http://pastebin.com/ApwQgG4w

Hope my question makes sense, if I have 2 workers for example it will set the 'alien' value to 4 every 5 seconds and I only want 2, For 3 I want 3 aliens every 5 seconds, not 9, etc.

Comment: The code you have provided in the question isn't sufficient to reproduce the problem. It would be helpful (for you and for us) if you edited your question to provide a minimal example that is capable of reproducing the problem. In doing so, it is possible that you will discover your bug.

Comment: It seems you may need to clear the `workerCheck` interval before resetting it. Otherwise, your code will add another timer each time you hire workers. [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval).

Comment: @TomFenech I don't understand? The code I provided is all I have? I am trying to find out why it's broken. When I have 2 workers it adds 2 to the alien counter, however it does it TWICE every 5 seconds. So in 5 seconds I will end up with 4 instead of 2 like I want it to. This happens on everything past 1 worker.

Comment: I just tested the code in your question, replacing the element `click()` with a `console.log` and it only fires twice every 5 seconds.

Comment: @TomFenech Here's an example. When I have 2 workers bought, I want it to click my alien automatically twice every 5 seconds. After 5 seconds passes, my total should increase by 2. HOWEVER, it currently increases by 4 for whatever reason and I don't know why. And that is only an example, it happens with every worker number past 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to clear your interval before resetting it.

When you click "Hire Workers" twice, two timers are created. Here's a [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/kq4xwh56/). You only want one timer no matter how many times the button is clicked.

When you call `setTimer()`, it returns a unique integer that you can use to reference that timer later. Since you are always setting (overwriting) the same variable `workerCheck` as the timer's unique integer, only the latest timer can be referenced by the `workerCheck` variable. Here's a [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/o43jme2h/).

I suggest that you clear the timer each time you reset it:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#Purchase').click(function () {
        automaticCounter();
    });

    // set variable with broader scope
    var workerCheck;

    function automaticCounter() {
        var workers = parseInt($("#Workers").text());
        workers = isNaN(workers) ? 0 : ++workers;

        $("#Workers").text(workers);

        var autoCounter = parseInt($("#Aliens").text());
        autoCounter = isNaN(autoCounter) ? 0 : autoCounter - 10 * workers;

        $("#Aliens").text(autoCounter);

        // clear the timer
        clearInterval(workerCheck);

        // set the timer
        workerCheck = setInterval(function () {
            var workers = parseInt($("#Workers").text());
            if (workers > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < workers; i++) {
                    $("#Alien").click();
                }
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ohzksd09/1/)

Comment: Similar fiddle over at http://jsfiddle.net/3z3765yn/ Only real difference is checking and setting of null for workerCheck variable rather than relying on uninitialized values.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood it right.

Here is a small but cool fiddle for you: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vcg4L3ne/)

Your Code Editted and its working now: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fssw4dh2/)

```
var workers = 0;
var workerCheck = setInterval(function(){
    workers = parseInt($("#workers").val());
        if( workers > 0 ){
            for(var i = 0; i < workers; i++){
            $("#Alien").trigger('click');       
            }
        }
},1000);
```

Whats wrong with your code: I don't know it a bit messy I edited it and its working now.

Comment: So what's the difference and what was wrong with the original code?

Comment: Don't no its a bit messy, added his code and fixed it.

Comment: Your second fiddle seems to work well. It looks like you've got the timer running constantly. That's not a bad idea to have a single global timer that updates the entire display, as opposed to setting a timer when you actually click the button. Seems a little cleaner.

Comment: @showdev - Agree but it really depend on what he is exactly doing (unclear) let say i purchased 2 workers (data base is updated Or cookie), now page is refreshed - the timer is not running until you purchase a new one :) but as i said it really depends on what he is doing and that's not clear.

Comment: Totally agree. Your "refreshed page" use case is a great example of how the constant timer method is superior. I also think your method allows more flexibility for additional logic in the future without having to add more independent timers. But yes, everything depends on the OP's desired functionality.